# Заэскепить символы Ruby (gsub!)

Tags: регулярные-выражения, ruby

Полчаса воюю с простой регуляркой.
Нужно экранировать некоторые символы для TeX

```
# \ % и т.д.

sub.gsub! /([\%#])/, '\\1'
```

Символ процента не трогает вообще

```
sub.gsub! /([\%#])/, '\\\1'
```

Не экранирует, но убирает.

Пробовал там #{$1} и т.д. безрезультатно

Comment: `sub.gsub! /([%#\\])/, '\\\\\\1'`

Comment: @Vadik, А почему столько слешей? 6 Штук.

Answer (score 1):

В Ruby чтобы представить обратный слэш в строке, его нужно экранировать обратным слэшом: `"\\"` или `'\\'`. Поэтому вам просто нужно удвоить количество слэшей:

```rb
"Какая\\то% строка#".gsub(/[\\%#]/, '\\\\\\0')
# => "Какая\\\\то\\% строка\\#"
```

В некоторых случаях Ruby может запутать, когда вы, например, пишете `'\n'` это на самом деле соответствует `'\\n'`:

```rb
'\n' == '\\n'
# => true
```

```rb
'\n' == "\\n"
# => true
```

При этом символ переноса строки это `"\n"`, но не `"\\n"`:

```rb
"\n" == "\\n"
# => false
```

Comment: Это работает, но не могу понять. Должно быть ТРИ слеша, один это \1, то что в скобках и конструкция \\. Откуда шесть берется?

Comment: `'\1'` это на самом деле `'\\1'`. Если бы вы использовали двойные кавычки, то написать `"\1"` было бы ошибкой, так как это соответствует символу с кодом 1, а не бекреференсу `"\\1"`

Comment: "конструкция \\" -- чтобы ее распечатать, нужно использовать четыре: `puts '\\\\'`

Comment: Руби позволяет писать `'\1'`, подразумевая, что это `'\\1'`, но лучше явно писать вторым вариантом, чтобы не было путаницы.